# Append sort route with search results in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-6

I want to append my search result `/search?allsearch=` and sort url `/search?sort=` together but I can't find the solution yet.
Here is my code:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 rounded left-addon-search inner-addon" action="/search" method="GET">
    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    <input type="text" name="allsearch" class="search-field rounded" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="search-addon" />
</form>

<select id="sort" name="sort">
    <option value="">Relevance</option>
    <option value="product_price_low_high" @if(isset($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort']=="product_price_low_high") selected="" @endif>Price: Low to High</option>
    <option value="product_price_high_low" @if(isset($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort']=="product_price_high_low") selected="" @endif>Price: High to Low</option>
    <option value="product_latest" @if(isset($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort']=="product_latest") selected="" @endif>Latest Arrivals</option>
</select>
```

My Controller:

```
$search = $request->allsearch;

$product = DB::table('brands')
    ->join('products', 'brands.id', '=', 'products.brandid')
    ->where('productname','like','%'.$search.'%')
    ->OrWhere('name','like','%'.$search.'%');

// sorting product
if (isset($_GET['sort']) && !empty($_GET['sort'])) {
    if ($_GET['sort'] == "product_price_low_high") {
        $product->orderBy('productprice', 'asc');
    } elseif ($_GET['sort'] == "product_price_high_low") {
        $product->orderBy('productprice', 'desc');
    } elseif($_GET['sort'] == "product_latest") {
        $product->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    }
}

$product = $product->get();
```

My route:

```
Route::get('/search','ProductController@search')->name('allsearch', 'sort');
```

Independently, the `/search?allsearch=` and the `/search?sort=` will work. But if I try to search for something, then sort the results, it clears out the search request.
Any idea how to make this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set the request value to the form so that you can work with both of them. you can use hidden input for the missing value in each form
the search form

```xml
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 rounded left-addon-search inner-addon" action="{{ route('search') }}" method="GET">
    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    <input type="text" name="allsearch" value="{{ request()->allsearch }}" class="search-field rounded" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="search-addon" />
    <input type="hidden" name="sort" value="{{ request()->sort }}" />
</form>
```

the sort form

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 rounded left-addon-search inner-addon" action="{{ route('search') }}" method="GET">
    <select id="sort" name="sort">
        <option value="">Relevance</option>
        <option value="product_price_low_high" @if (request()->sort == "product_price_low_high") selected @endif>Price: Low to High</option>
        <option value="product_price_high_low" @if (request()->sort == "product_price_high_low") selected @endif>Price: High to Low</option>
        <option value="product_latest" @if (request()->sort == "product_latest") selected @endif>Latest Arrivals</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="allsearch" value="{{ request()->allsearch }}" />
</form>
```

why your route has two names?? route shuold have a single unique name

```
Route::get('search', 'ProductController@search')->name('search');
```

and in controller

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $search = $request->allsearch;

    $product = DB::table('brands')
        ->join('products', 'brands.id', '=', 'products.brandid')
        ->where('productname', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');

    if ($request->sort == "product_price_low_high") {
        $product->orderBy('productprice', 'asc');
    } elseif ($request->sort == "product_price_high_low") {
        $product->orderBy('productprice', 'desc');
    } elseif ($request->sort == "product_latest") {
        $product->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    }

    $product = $product->get();
    return response/view
}
```

> you are using laravel, so try to code as the laravel way

Comment: what if the select form and input search were in the different pages? is it using the same action form too? ive already tried but its not working

Comment: search and sort are in two different page with separate forms?? like with search you return to a new page and then you sort??

Comment: then you can use hidden input. updating the answer.

Comment: you're my life saver! it's working fine now. thankyou very much